# TWAPI TCL The target principal name is incorrect

Tags: windows, ssl, ssl-certificate, tcl

I have a file on a server and I am trying to read it.
My code is as follows:

```
package require http
package require twapi_crypto
http::register https 443 [list ::twapi::tls_socket]
set token [http::geturl "https://$ipaddress/filename"]
set status [http::status $token]
set data [http::data $token]
put $data
```

and I get the following error:

```
The target principal name is incorrect
while executing
"InitializeSecurityContext  $Credentials  $Handle  $Target  $Inattr  0  $Datarep  $inbuflist  0"
    (procedure "sspi_step" line 16)
    invoked from within
"sspi_step $SpiContext $data"
    (procedure "_negotiate2" line 19)
    invoked from within
"_negotiate2 $chan"
    (procedure "rethrow" line 2)
    invoked from within
"rethrow"
    invoked from within
"trap {
_negotiate2 $chan
} onerror {} {
variable channels
if {[info exists _channels($chan)]} {
dict set _chan..."
    (procedure "_negotiate line 3)
    invoked from within
"_negotiate $chan"
    (procedure "::twapi::tls::_so_write_andler" line12)
    invoked from within
"::twapi::tls::_so_write_handle rc0"
```

Can somebody redirect me here where the issue is?  I get warning from IE when I am trying to access the file and have to click continue even though I have added the certificate to the browser, This is running on a windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the subject Common Name on the certificate isn't matching the IP address you're passing in, which is to be expected. You have to use the host *name* when opening an HTTPS connection.

```
# Use the right hostname of course
set hostname "securetesting.example.com"

set token [http::geturl "https://$hostname/filename"]
```

This because that name is used to determine whether the server that you've connected to is the one that you've asked to connect to. Without that, it could be a secure connection *to absolutely anyone* and that's not a useful kind of security! Yes, this means that you need to spend some time getting DNS right as part of deploying, and yes, this is a bit of a pain. Security usually is.

Interestingly, you should also give the hostname properly even with plain unencrypted HTTP as servers can host multiple sites. The only time you get away with it is when talking unencrypted to a server that only serves up a single site; the web hasn't really worked that way for many years.